# Most efficient way to merge two partially inclusive lists of files and their properties

Tags: python, performance, list, dictionary

I have a system that runs a custom cli with a variation of the `ls` or `dir` command, returning a list of files and folders in your working directory.

The problem is, I can either run the command with a flag that returns the files and their time stamps (date created and last modified), or one that returns the file and their file sizes. There is no way to get both in a single cli command.

A further complication arises when getting the time stamped list, only some of the files are returned (all files ending in certain prefixes are left out). Neither list is in any particular order.

I wish to create a dictionary that contains all the information for each file in one place. What is the cleanest, most efficient, and most pythonic way to do this?

**Quick sample of data:**

`dir -time` gives a list of 506 elements. Only (but not all) files ending in .ts have timestamps. Some files show in the list but do not have timestamps, some files (such as anything ending in .index) do not show up in the list at all.

```
ch20prefix_20_182.ts    2014-10-22 16:06:20 - 2014-10-22 16:08:51                                                                    
ch21prefix_21_40.ts     2014-10-14 16:15:42 - 2014-10-14 16:16:51                                                       
modinfo_sdk1.23b24L                                                                                                     
bs780_ntplatency                                                                                                        
ch10prefix_10_237.ts    2014-10-27 11:05:10 - 2014-10-27 11:07:33                                                       
ch10prefix_10_277.ts    2014-10-30 14:03:51 - 2014-10-30 14:04:24                                                                                                                                                                    
video1_6_1.ts                                                                                                           
ch11prefix_11_179.ts    2014-10-22 14:53:50 - 2014-10-22 14:56:00`
```

`dir -size` gives a list of 967 elements. All files are present here, all files have a file size.

```
ch10prefix_10_340.index 159544
ch2prefix_2_705.ts      75958204
<ts220> 0
ch11prefix_11_148.ts    19877616
ch10prefix_10_310.ts    7373924
ch11prefix_11_111.index 17112
ch11prefix_11_278.index 1368
ch2prefix_2_307.ts      6492580
channelConfig.xml.2HD   18144
ch21prefix_21_220.ts    12893604
ch20prefix_20_128.index 1720
```

There is some rhyme and reason to the mess that is why some files show up and others don't, why some have timestamps and others don't, but that is largely irrelevant to this question.

**My thoughts on how to approach it:**

What I want as final output is a dictionary with each key as a file name, and it's value as another dictionary with key/val pairs for Time Created, Time Mod, fileSize. This way one can easily lookup all 3 pieces of information for each file.

The difficult part for me, however, is finding an efficient way of combining the data from each list. The first thing that comes to mind would be to loop through the larger list (file size), and then for each element, check if it is in the smaller list, and if it is (and has a timestamp), add the data. But that is horridly inefficient. Although some files in the larger list I know ahead of time do not have timestamps in the other list, I cannot say that for all files that don't have a timestamp.

The lists are unsorted, but It occurs to me that if they were sorted by file name, that allow for a much faster way of looking up each file from one list in another, but considering the runtime of sorting the lists, it still might not be worth the effort.

So, what would be the most efficient approach here? I am mostly concerned with run-time and readability, but welcome the inclusion of other factors in how I might approach this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "a custom cli"? Can you not just locally get a working version of `ls`?

Comment: Have you looked at [os.stat](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat), [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk), [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) ?

Comment: You only want files common to both *lists*?

Comment: Rather than only writing the most efficient code, why not write something that solves the problem then see how long it takes to run.  If it takes too long start optimizing.

Comment: @Blender. This needs to be done through a remote connection, and while `ls` would technically work, it would not be robust enough for my purposes.  One problem with SE can be trying to describe a problem without giving away unnecessary levels of detail, or describing internal/proprietary elements that took me weeks to learn.

Comment: @wwii. Sorry, I should have been more precise, I want all files. If a file does not appear on one list, it still is in the final resulting dict, but will only have key/val pair for the file size, not the time-stamps, since none are available. And I'd really like to know how something like this can be optimized as more of a general case, not just for this one problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell from your question what your desired result is.  If you want all files in both lists even if they only appear in one or the other just make one pass through both files and create a dictionary using `collections.defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(dict)
with open('fileA.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        name, time = line[:24], line[24:]
        name, time = name.strip(), time.strip()
        time_created, time_modified = time.split(' - ')
        d[name]['time_created'] = time_created
        d[name]['time_modified'] = time_modified

with open('fileB.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        name, size = line[:24], line[24:]
        name, size = name.strip(), size.strip()
        d[name]['size'] = size
```

---

If your final result only includes files that appear in both lists then make one pass over each list constructing separate dictionaries.

```
dA = defaultdict(dict)
dB = defaultdict(dict)

with open('fileA.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        name, time = line[:24], line[24:]
        name, time = name.strip(), time.strip()
        try:
            time_created, time_modified = time.split(' - ')
        except ValueError:
            time_created, time_modified = '', ''
        dA[name]['time_created'] = time_created
        dA[name]['time_modified'] = time_modified

with open('fileB.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        name, size = line[:24], line[24:]
        name, size = name.strip(), size.strip()
        dB[name]['size'] = size
```

Then make a pass over one of those dictionaries creating a third dictionary with common keys.

```
d = defaultdict(dict)
for k, v in dA.items():
    if k in dB:
        d[k] = v
        d[k].update(dB[k])
```

---

Since this is the only answer (so far) with a solution And @Brian C didn't offer one, this MUST be the most efficient.

Comment: I want all files in the final result. Sorry for not specifying that. I did offer a solution, but It seemed very inefficient so I did not bother to put it into actual code. I will try your suggestion and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a good use case for Sqlite. 
Python has [good support](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) for it. Instead of creating a disk file based DB you could use a pure in-memory based database by passing the right arguments. First I'd create a 2 tables - tblFileNTimeStamp (File name (PK), timestamp) and tblFileNSize (File name (PK), filesize). Use the output of the two commands to populate the database and use a join on the primary keys to pick the results you need.

Comment: Why would sqlite be any better than a Python dictionary in this case?

Comment: @Blender I don't see any reason a dictionary wouldnt do, One can only truely know which is better when the performance is measured (time, memory).